# Unexpected scrollbar

Tags: html, css

How come there is a vertical scrollbar visible with this HTML file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
   html, body {border:0; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%}
   h1 {margin:1em}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

(or this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfxWL/))

The body has exactly the same height as the window, obviously. So, what makes the content larger? What am I missing?
(Tested with IE, FF, Chrome.)

Comment: `max-height` instead of `height` resolved this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is called "[collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)". Since your `h1` element is the first child element of `body`, it tries to collapse margin with it and the margin of `h1` ends up at the `body` tag. Since `body` is already 100% the added margin will make it larger than the viewport.

[Read more on collapsing margins on w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: But... but... does this collapsing make the margin on body _larger?_ Oh. I see I need to read up on the definition of "collapse". Thanks anyway.

Comment: yes it does, that's why it produces a result that you didn't expect. :) The margin is actually moved to the body element.

Answer (score 2):

The margin on your h1 element is expanding the content of your body which is already 100% of the height. Exceeding 100% of the height is causing the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
 html {border:0; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%}
      body {border:0; margin:0; padding:0}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `height: 100%` or add `overflow: hidden`. But be careful - 100% means only 100% of your initial screen.

Comment: No, I don't want the overflow to be hidden; the document needs to have a scrollbar if the content is actually larger than the window. And removing the height would mess up the background if the content is smaller. But thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `h1` element's top `margin` is being calculated from the top of the document.

You could use `padding` in this example instead.

Comment: I thought I knew how the calculations worked. And since the h1 was inside the body, and body didn't have any margins or padding, I thought the h1 couldn't affect the body. Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: Margin is the space between the current element and the next element with a padding/margin/border. I don't know who downvoted, but feel free to leave a comment and I'll explain what you must not understand.